# Date Formatting in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I use a spreadsheet in my medical office for referrals. It includes places to fill in these three areas: date faxed, date of the appointment, date the appointment office notes were received. The problem is that sometimes people don't go to the appointments. I want the 'date of the appointment' box to highlight in yellow if it has been *1 month* since the 'date faxed' and no appointment date has been entered. I also want to have the 'date of the appointment' box changed to a red highlight if it has been *6 months* since the 'date faxed' and no appointment date has been entered. How would I go about doing this on the Google drive spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Google spreadsheet's conditional formatting is much more limited than Excel. You can only change a cell's color based on its own value, not the value of other cells. So you'll have to add a new column.

Let's say that Column A is the Date Faxed, Column B is Appointment Date.

1. Create Column C called "Days Elapsed". Go to cell C2 and give it a formula of
   `=if(isblank(B2), today()-A2, "")`
   What that does is calculate the Days Elapsed since Date Faxed, or if there's a value for Appointment Date, then leave it blank.
2. Fill Down the formula from C2 to the bottom of the sheet.
3. Select the entire Column C. Format > Conditional formatting. Add rules:

   a. if greater than 180, background red
   b. if greater than 30, background yellow

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. `date faxed` is in A1
2. `date of the appointment` is in B1
3. `date the appointment office notes were received` is in C1

then with New Google Sheets enter:

in B1 Custom formula is `=today()-30>A1`
in C1 Custom formula is `=and(isblank(C1),today()-180>A1)`

with Background to suit.

I have approximated one month as 30 days and six months as 180 days but it might be possible to be more precise if required.